# Spring-Webflow Using a HTML link to signal an event

Tags: spring-webflow, zk

I am playing around with Spring-Webflow (2.3), ZK (5.0.7.1) and ZK Spring (3.0).

Actually I'm trying to signal an event with a HTML link as described at [Spring-Webflow](http://static.springsource.org/spring-webflow/docs/2.3.x/reference/html/ch11s06.html).

```
<a href="${flowExecutionUrl}&_eventId=go2ProjectRoomView" >2 Project</a>
```

Part of my flow definition file looks like:

```
<view-state id="mainView">
  <transition on="go2ProjectRoomView" to="projectRoomView" bind="false"/>
</view-state>

<view-state id="projectRoomView">
  <transition on="go2MainView" to="mainView" bind="false"/>
</view-state>
```

If I deploy my web project and navigate to the main view following error appears:

```
The reference to entity "_eventId" must end with the ';' delimiter
```

Same error happens if I replace `_eventId=go2ProjectRoomView` by `_eventId_go2ProjectRoomView`.

Link to [full stack trace](http://pastebin.com/bzHjyqDy).

Comment: I'm facing same problem and I tried th:href too without results. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 7):

The error you are receiving is actually an HTML/XML parsing error.  Ampersand (&) is used to reference special characters/entities (see [here](http://www.w3schools.com/HTML/html_entities.asp)).  Change your link to:

```
<a href="${flowExecutionUrl}&amp;_eventId=go2ProjectRoomView" >2 Project</a>
```

and you should be ok.

Comment: Thanks for your help. The error i mentioned doesn't appear anymore. Unfortunately the next view state connected to the thrown event will not be displayed. :-(

Comment: From the code you posted, you do not have the view attribute defined for either of your view-states.  You need to specify this so WebFlow knows what view it should render when it enters that particular state.

Comment: If no view name is defined spring assumes the id as the view name. But I tried it nevertheless and it doesn't help. The view will be rendered if i write the following: <zul:button label="Taskboard" onClick="" self="@{action(go2TaskBoardView)}" />

Comment: You are right, I was not aware of this shortcut for the view name.  You might consider posting a new question with more information about the new problem you are having.